# What were the two bugs sent to kill Padme called?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

I watched *Star Wars: Attack of the Clones* the other day, in which a drone sent indirectly by Jango Fett sends two millipede-like creatures to kill Padme in her sleep.

I was wondering if they had a name and exactly what they could do. Would they just have strangled Padme? Or would they have poisoned her?

Comment: Their names were Bob and Tony Kounun. Interestingly, they were actually sentient creatures who didn't want to harm Padmé. They just wanted her autograph.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Star Wars: Attack of the Clones The Visual Dictionary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Attack_of_the_Clones_The_Visual_Dictionary) factbook identifies them as **Kouhuns** as well as offering an explanation for their use over the more obvious explosive or projectile weapons that Wesell could have employed.

> **KOUHUNS**
>
> *Zam uses two deadly kouhuns for her Senatorial assassination Job.
>   Small, silent arthropods like the kouhuns of Indoumodo can evade even
>   tight security. **Unlike projectiles or energy weapons, they are
>   virtually impossible to trace back to their users.** Kouhuns are starved
>   in advance, so they head straight for warm-blooded life forms when
>   released, and **use a fast-acting nerve toxin to kill their prey.***

[image]

The [Official Databank article](https://www.starwars.com/databank/kouhun) notes that their poison is *especially deadly to humanoids.*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [Kouhuns](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kouhun)

[Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Plot_to_assassinate_Padm%C3%A9_Amidala) says that

> Following the first failed attempt, Wesell was sent by Fett to end the life of Amidala a second time. Fett, thinking that a more subtle attempt would be more desirable, gave Wesell two **kouhuns**, a type of arthropod with **a venom capable of easily killing adult Humans**. Wesell placed the kouhuns in her ASN courier droid and sent it to place the kouhuns in Amidala's bedroom.

So

1. They're called kouhuns.
2. They are poisonous, and have a lethal venom that is able to kill adults.